# Access cell of a column using a given index?

Tags: java, javafx-2, tableview

I have the index (as integer) of a cell in a `TableColumn` of a `TableView`. Using the index of the cell, how can I access the cell object at this index? I am missing something like

```
tableColumn.getCells()
```

which would then allow me to access the cell with the given index:

```
tableColumn.getCells().get(index)
```

Any hints on this? Thanks!

**Update:**

As per request, a use case for this:

Imagine a music playlist. For some reasons I am using a TableView for that and the TableView is as big as possible, meaning even if there are just 5 music tracks in the playlist and there is space for 10 rows, then 10 rows (5 filled, 5 empty) are shown.

I then implemented drag & drop for re-arranging items. Now imagine a user wants to place the second entry to the end of the playlist. He drags the second entry, but not directly over the last used table row, but on e.g. row 8. In that case I want to give a visual feedback that the music track is placed under the last used row (row 5, but the mouse is over row/cell 8!), so I need to modify row/cell 5, while the mouse is over row 8. Knowing which row is the last filled one is quite easy - it's tableview.getItems().size()-1, but getting a reference to row/cell 5 is a tricky thing / my problem here.

Comment: Is that what you need? http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/TableColumn.html#getCellData(int)

Comment: Thanks, but no, this gives me the data *in* the cell, but I need a reference to the cell itself, so I can change its style using cell.setStyle(..)

Comment: I think, you should add suport of cell.setStyle() from cellFactory. When you add a cell factory to a column, add logic of adding cell in some special list, or smth like that. I don't think there is support of such operation, because it is not supposed, that you operate with components of data representation (cell/row) directly after their creation.

Comment: Thanks, I am already using a cellFactory, but in one special case I need to modify a cell A when a cell B is hovered. Creating my own List is an idea, I am just wondering if it's really necessary \:

Comment: As you see from Sergey's comment,  it should be a tricky logic.

Answer (score 1):

This API doesn't exist for a reason.

For better performance FX `TableView` manipulates cells by itself. Cells are created and destroyed depending on currently visible part of the TableView and other parameters. Even more: cell objects can be reused to represent data from other cells under some circumstances.

So return value of `tableColumn.getCells().get(index)` is not determinate, thus there is no API to receive it.

All cell related logic should be implemented in the `CellFactory` callback.

Can you describe what kind of logic you want to implement by accessing cells?

Comment: I see several requests on work with cells. We may think about rfe on cells access somehow

Comment: I added a use case to my original question, please let me know if that is understandable (and if there is a better way than manually tracking all cells)

Answer (score 0):

I would set a fixed cell size and just take a guess using the mouse coordinates.  I just added it to an existing example and I'm sure it's not quite right but it shows the idea.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.chart.PieChart;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.TextFieldTableCell;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.converter.NumberStringConverter;

public class ChangePie extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        ObservableList<PieChart.Data> pieChartData
                = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                        new PieChart.Data("Grapefruit", 13),
                        new PieChart.Data("Oranges", 25),
                        new PieChart.Data("Plums", 10),
                        new PieChart.Data("Pears", 22),
                        new PieChart.Data("Apples", 30));
        final PieChart chart = new PieChart(pieChartData);
        chart.setTitle("Imported Fruits");

        final TableView<PieChart.Data> tv = new TableView(pieChartData);
        tv.setEditable(true);
        tv.setFixedCellSize(40);

        tv.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.ANY, (MouseEvent evt) -> {
            double y = 0;
            int idx1 = 0, idx2 = 0;
            if (evt.getEventType() == MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED) {
                y = evt.getY();
                idx1 = tv.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex();
            } else if (evt.getEventType() == MouseEvent.MOUSE_RELEASED) {
                idx2 = (int) Math.round((evt.getY() - y) / 40);
                System.out.println("insert at " + idx2);
                if (idx2 > 0) {
                    chart.setData(null);
                    PieChart.Data removed = pieChartData.remove(idx1);
                    pieChartData.add(Math.min(idx2, pieChartData.size() - 1), removed);
                }
            }

        });

        TableColumn tc1 = new TableColumn("Name");
        tc1.setPrefWidth(100);
        tc1.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("name"));
        tc1.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());

        TableColumn tc2 = new TableColumn("Data");
        tc2.setPrefWidth(100);
        tc2.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("pieValue"));
        tc2.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn(new NumberStringConverter()));

        tv.getColumns().addAll(tc1, tc2);
        Scene scene = new Scene(new VBox(chart, tv));
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```